# "Summary" vs "A summary" vs "The summary"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Let's suppose my manager asks me to research some problem. I've done this and now I'm going to write him a message:

> **A/the summary**:
>
> [The problem is caused by this and that ...]

Do I need any article (a/the) before "summary"?

Comment: You do not say whether you are talking about a title or text. If it is a title in an informal or internal document, I'd say "Summary of ..." If it is a title in a public or very formal document such as a scholarly article, I'd say "A Summary of ..." If it is a reference in the body of the summary, I'd say "this summary." In other words, context matters. Please clarify your question.

Comment: Well, I'm talking about a message. The content of the message is: "A/the summary: The problem is caused by this and that ...". This is a correspondence between me and my manager.

Comment: In that case, I'd say "The summary about ... will be ready by close of business today." My point remains: context is critical.

Comment: Thank you, @JeffMorrow

Comment: What's the *exact* context? Are you asking whether to include an article in ***the title of an email**?*

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica No, I'm NOT talking about a title. I'm talking about the message itself. Let's say I'm replying to a message - the title is already there, I can't edit it. But I'm replying with the following text: "A/the summary: The problem you asked me to look into is caused by this and that ..."

Comment: @ChrisBrettini: oic. Well, *semantically / orthographically* it still looks pretty much like a "title" to me - particularly since in your *question* text, you've put it on a separate line, which is how headlines / titles / bullet points normally work. Personally, I don't think things like this are really to do with "grammar / syntax". It looks more like "page layout" to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica OK, thank you!